# Find the coordinates of u := (1, 0, 3) with respect to $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let v1 = ($\frac{\sqrt11}{11}$,$\frac{\sqrt-11}{11}$ ,$\frac{\sqrt{-11}}{11}$), v2 = ($\frac{\sqrt6}{3}$, $\frac{\sqrt-6}{6}$, $\frac{\sqrt-6}{6}$) and v3 = ($\frac{\sqrt66}{3}$, $\frac{\sqrt66}{66}$, $\frac{\sqrt66}{66}$).

(i) Find the coordinates of u := (1, 0, 3) with respect to $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$.

I put everything into an augmented matrix and my plan was to reduce it to reduced row echelon form. Can I do this seeing as I have radicals?

Any advice on how I should begin would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I compute that  rank of augmented matrix and rank of coefficient matrix are different, I think there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

$u=x_1 v_1+x_2 v_2+x_3 v_3$ and we want to find $x_1,x_2,x_3$

Let $A=[v_1^T~~ v_2^T ~~v_3^T]$ be the square matrix, so we have

$(x_1, x_2, x_3)^T=A^{-1}u^T$